# What is = for in front of argument in Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I searched for the Ruby method but I was not able find what I was looking for. In the following method definition, it has = sign before the argument. I want to know how/when to use.

```
def age=(value)
  @age = value
end
```

Do I need a bracket? Can I write like this?

```
def age=value
  @age = value
end
```

Is it the same as followings?

```
def age (value)
  @age = value
end
```

OR

```
def age (value=value)
  @age = value
end
```

I am a Ruby beginner.

Comment: Why don't you try to run it yourself since you already line it out? (BTW I didn't downvote it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` means it's a "setter" for a class. It can be defined as:

```
def age=(value)
  @age = value
end
```

or

```
def age= value
  @age = value
end
```

When so defined, if you have an instance of the class, say `foo`, then you can do this:

```
foo.age = 10
```

And it will set the value of `@age` for the class instance.

You could do this this as well:

```
def age(value)
  @age = value
end
```

or

```
def age value
  @age = value
end
```

And then you'd need to call it like this:

```
foo.age(10)
```

Functionally, it does almost the same thing. But a `setter` can be used in cases where you are doing meta-programming with setters.

Answer (score 3):

```
# method name is age= 
def age=(value)
  @age = value
end   
age = 1   #=> sets @age as 1
age=(1)  #=> sets @age as 1

# same as before, parenthesis are needed when the method has multiple inputs
def age=value
  @age = value
end
age = 1   #=> sets @age as 1
age=(1)  #=> sets @age as 1

# method name is age
def age (value)
  @age = value 
end
age 1  #=> sets @age as 1
age(1) #=> sets @age as 1

# method name is age and the value argument has a default value of 1
def age (value=1)
   @age = value
end
age #=> sets @age as 1
age 2 #=> sets @age as 2

# this is not a valid declaration unless value is a defined method on the object
def age(value=value)
   @age = value
end
```